# What does the "r" in-between two words mean, especially in Naam-Stotram?

Tags: sanskrit, stotra

In Nama-stotra I often come across the "r" in between words. What exactly does it serve as or mean? For example,
mokṣalakṣmī**r**maharddhidā. Could Sanskrit adept please clarify this?

Comment: it's Moksha Lakshmihi + Maha.. after Sandhi visarga become "r"

Comment: What is Lakshmihi? And sandhi visarga??

Comment: Voting to close because this is not a question about Hinduism.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about this, it's just regular Sanskrit grammar. If you want to learn Sanskrit grammar, you should learn Sanskrit grammar. If you don't, you probably won't get very far in your religious observances by going through Sanskrit phrases letter-by-letter.

In any case, what you have here is मोक्षलक्ष्मीः+महर्द्धिदा (*mokṣalakṣmīḥ+maharddhidā*). The two dots that resemble an English colon are called *visarga*. It is typical to pronounce this as a *h* with a slight echo of the vowel that comes before it, hence नमः *namaḥ* is pronounced *namaha*, शान्तिः *śāntiḥ* is pronounced *shaantihi*, etc. ईः + म = ईर्म (*īḥ* + *ma* = *īrma*). Actually *visarga* becomes र् *r* before any voiced sound except र् *r*, unless the *visarga* comes after अ/आ (*a/ā*) (which is probably why you see this so often). This is a standard Sanskrit sandhi rule. Sandhi is where sounds change when they occur together. All languages have this, but not all languages write these changes down. Sanskrit is very meticulous in showing all of these changes in the spelling. But we can see similar things happen in English. For example, see how *in-* changes in the following words: *i**m**possible, i**n**direct, i**l**logical, i**r**responsible.* This can even happen between words. For example, *gotcha* is a colloquial pronunciation of *got you* where *t* + *y* has become *ch* (and sometimes we even spell it like that!)

The reason it's मोक्षलक्ष्मीः *mokṣalakṣmīḥ* with the *visarga* on the end is because it is in the nominative singular. (Actually the  *visarga* is quite unusual in the nominative singular of words that end in ई *ī*, but लक्ष्मी *lakṣmī* happens to be a word that has it. *Visarga* is an extremely common nominative singular ending in other stems, though.) So the point is, the ending of the word gives us grammatical information. I have told you मोक्षलक्ष्मीः *mokṣalakṣmīḥ* is singular: there is only one. Compare how in English you have *one apple* (singular) but *two apple**s*** (plural). The *s* ending tells us there is more than one. मोक्षलक्ष्मीः *mokṣalakṣmīḥ* is singular, मोक्षलक्ष्म्याः *mokṣalakṣmyāḥ* would be plural I suppose. I have also told you that it is nominative. In a simple, active voice sentence like *Lakshmi sees Rama*, the subject (the seer, the doer of the action, whatever it is) will be in the nominative, thus (without sandhi): **लक्ष्मीः** रामम् पश्यति ***lakṣmīḥ** rāmam paśyati* "Lakshmi sees Rama", but रामः **लक्ष्मीम्** पश्यति *rāmaḥ **lakṣmīm** paśyati* "Rama sees Lakshmi". Compare English ***I** saw him*, but *he saw **me***.